# How do I select user id, first and last name directly from Wordpress database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm creating a autosuggest for searching for a user in Wordpress.
The problem is that first and last name is stored as meta_key.

So "normal" search is not possible.

I probably have to do two queries. Is it possible to do a `JOIN`?

Here is my unsuccessful first attempt:

```
SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name 
FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE (meta_key='first_name' OR meta_key='last_name' OR meta_key = 'user_email') 
AND LOWER(meta_value) LIKE '%jon%'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer. I'm not sure if this is the best one, but it works:

```
SELECT a.id, b1.meta_value AS first_name, b2.meta_value as last_name
FROM wp_users a
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta b1 ON b1.user_id = a.ID AND b1.meta_key = 'first_name' 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta b2 ON b2.user_id = a.ID AND b2.meta_key = 'last_name'
WHERE (b1.meta_value LIKE '%st%' OR b2.meta_value LIKE '%st%' OR a.user_email LIKE '%st%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT um.user_id, um.meta_key, um.meta_value, u.user_email
FROM wp_usermeta AS um
INNER JOIN wp_users AS u ON (u.ID = um.user_id)
WHERE meta_key IN ('first_name', 'last_name')
AND (meta_value LIKE '%jon%' OR u.user_email LIKE '%jon%')
```

Comment: That kind of works. But I would prefer to have id, first_name,last_name columns instead of meta_key and meta_value columns. I don't need e-mail column

Answer (score 0):

you can use thr get_users() function

```
  // code to use
  $args = array(
  'meta_key' => 'first_name',
  'meta_value' => 'SomeName',
  'meta_key' => 'last_name',
  'meta_value' => 'SomeName2',
  );
  $users = get_users( $args );
```

then

```
 foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo '<li>' . $user->user_email . '</li><br>';
    echo '<li>' . $user->display_name. '</li>';
    //data you want to dispaly
    /*
       [ID] => 1
       [user_login] => admin
       [user_pass] => $P$Bxudi6gJMk2GRt2ed3xvZ06c1BPZXi/
       [user_nicename] => admin
       [user_email] => admin@host.com
       [user_url] => http://localhost/
       [user_registered] => 2010-06-29 07:08:55
       [user_activation_key] => 
       [user_status] => 0
       [display_name] => Richard Branson
    */
 }
```

more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users

Good Luck.

Comment: How would you use that to find all users starting with `jo`? E.g. joe, john, johnny, joseph and so on.